# How to activate multiply versions of PHP in (mac OS 2022)

Tags: php, version-control

I have Xammp installed on my Mac. However, when I want to work on different PHP versions.

**I got this error**

```
    - Root composer.json requires php ^7.3 but your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.         Problem 2
    - asm89/stack-cors is locked to version v2.0.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - asm89/stack-cors v2.0.1 requires php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 3
    - laravel/framework is locked to version v8.10.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - laravel/framework v8.10.0 requires php ^7.3 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 4
    - laravel/tinker is locked to version v2.4.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - laravel/tinker v2.4.2 requires php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 5
    - facade/flare-client-php is locked to version 1.3.6 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - facade/flare-client-php 1.3.6 requires php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 6
    - facade/ignition is locked to version 2.4.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - facade/ignition 2.4.1 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 7
    - fzaninotto/faker is locked to version v1.9.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - fzaninotto/faker v1.9.1 requires php ^5.3.3 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 8
    - nunomaduro/collision is locked to version v5.0.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - nunomaduro/collision v5.0.2 requires php ^7.3 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 9
    - asm89/stack-cors v2.0.1 requires php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - fruitcake/laravel-cors v2.0.2 requires asm89/stack-cors ^2.0.1 -> satisfiable by asm89/stack-cors[v2.0.1].
    - fruitcake/laravel-cors is locked to version v2.0.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
```

How can I switch versions.

Comment: the easyest way i do on windows is installing two Xampp in different folders with different version of php

Comment: [Try this guide](https://www.markhesketh.com/switching-multiple-php-versions-on-macos/)

Comment: Or you can use docker as an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch between multiple versions of PHP using these commands:

1. `sudo update-alternatives --config php`
2. `sudo update-alternatives --config phar`
3. `sudo update-alternatives --config phar.phar`

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It finally works! thanks brother.